# Issue with C#' generics, how to pass through input and output via a Func

Tags: c#, generics, func

```
private static K ExecuteStoredProcedure<K>(string connectionString, string storedProcedure, SqlParameter[] parameters, Func<I, K> readFunction)
```

Example usage is shown below:

```
 return ExecuteStoredProcedure<SqlDataReader, Dictionary<string, string>>(
     connectionString, 
     "uspSearchStatisticsSelectByTokenPerDayGroupByDate", 
     parameters, 
     (reader) =>
     {
         reader.Read();
         int readCount = reader.FieldCount;

         Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         results.Add("FailedRequests", Convert.ToString(reader[5]));
         results.Add("TotalRequests", Convert.ToString(reader[4]));
         results.Add("AverageResponseTime", Convert.ToString(reader[3]));

         return results;
     }
 );
```

The compiler comes back with

> Error 520 The type or namespace name 'I' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

but I thought it should be able to reference that?

Update: I was trying to go for something too generic and didn't really need it.

I've gone with the following...
`private static K ExecuteStoredProcedure<K>(string connectionString, string storedProcedure, SqlParameter[] parameters, Func<SqlDataReader, K> readFunction)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function is generic over `I` and `K`. The signature needs to be:

```
K ExecuteStoredProcedure<I, K>(...)
```

Comment: Ta, figured that out just after you posted.Given I was pretty much going to be a SqlDataReader I probably over complicated it!! :)

Answer (score 2):

As the input parameter of the function is known, it shouldn't be generic. Just make the parameter `Func<SqlDataReader, K> readFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

Your static method at the top declares only one type parameter, called `K`. Did you mean to have two, like `static K ExecuteStoredProcedure<I, K>( ... )`? Because when you call the method, you do supply two type parameters.

The compiler error is quite clear: You say `Func<I, K>`, but nowhere is a type `I` defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your reader is only returning Dictionary and on how you are using your code K = Dictionary so you are missing the value for I, maybe you declare bad the functions or you need to fix the return value.